# Printable badges

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges, printing

It would be nice to have PDF-printable tag badges, sort of certification style. For example, it took me years to collect a gold for a certain tag and I am really proud of it, so I would print and frame it.

A very basic example:

[image]

Though a certificate style paper is always a whole page, something like:

[image]

Comment: It's a yellow circle.  You could style one yourself with little effort.  If it's one of the unique ones for a site, just zoom in.

Comment: Why? It would be out of date the moment it comes out of the printer and nobody is going to sign it without having verified your identity.

Comment: @Mast I do not want to have something official. Just put it on my wall along with my 3 degrees and other stuff.

Comment: So, your flair would suffice? [Here is yours](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/300083.png). Scale it up a bit, or generate something automatically [from your account page](https://stackexchange.com/users/300083/inf3rno?tab=accounts). A neat HTML page extracting the data into an A4 styled document is all you'd need then if it doesn't have to be official.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be really nice that each badge have a full-screen, visually compelling, print-friendly view.

Slightly related, there are at least two [feature-requests](/questions/tagged/feature-requests)
asking that the company become a [open badges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Open_Badges) issuer. Open badges is the digital version of the paper education/training/skills certificates. While the most important part is the data and verification, it includes a visual representation to be shown on personal web pages, social media, etc.

- [Can Stack Exchange support the Mozilla Open Badges service?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139553/289691) from 2012
- [Issue badges as open digital badges (Open Badges)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285830/289691) from 2016

Related

- [Will the badges ever have a design to them instead of just having colors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1596/289691) from 2009
- [Graphical Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38330/289691) from 2010
- [Why are badges motivating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61729/289691) from 2010
- [Can I automatically post earned badges to my Facebook status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71046/289691) from 2010
- [Display specific earned badges as profile bling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168227/289691) from 2013
- [Can we have a page that lets us show off a specific badge we've earned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176300/289691) from 2013
- [Add option to show one badge in flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203636/289691) from 2013

Comment: @inf3rno I just found a very old feature request asking for having a design for each badge (added the link to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I believe all the badge icons are in SVG format (scaleable vector graphics), which means they can be upscaled without loss of quality (they don't define pixels, but sets of coordinates between which lines or polygons are drawn). The fonts, while they may not be as important anyway and might differ from machine to machine and browser to browser (e.g. in my case (Windows 10/Firefox) *Segoe UI Adjusted* is used), will scale nicely zooming in in your browser, or you can use an image editor like Photoshop to recreate it.

You can go to your Badges page, use your browser's Inspector to find the file that contains the icon:

[image]

In the case shown that's "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/gaming/img/sprites.svg":

[image]

And you can Print Screen it there zoomed in, or download the file and edit it in along with the description in the right font in your favourite image editor software:

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. The OP isn’t looking to print the gold dot, but rather to print a certificate or reward you typically see in academic or business. Something you’d hang on a wall. You wouldn’t hang a gold dot on the wall.

Comment: @JamesRisner Well, if it is real gold. :D I edited the question after this answer, because apparently most people misunderstood it.

Comment: @JamesRisner I don't agree with your reasoning, because that's subjective, but your conclusion seems to be correct.